# How to keep track of XML Feed on Google analytics

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, google-analytics

We are providing functionality to other site to use articles from our site.We are sending them by RSS feed. (http://www.feedforall.com/sample-feed.xml)

We are working on Asp.net c#.
Client requesting feed like. `www.example.com/feed.aspx?startdate=2015-07-07`
and we are sending this in output stream.

```
rssFeed.Save(Response.OutputStream);
```

We need to keep track this request on google analytic.
GA is scripting. and we need to call function like below from html page.

```
ga('send', 'event','xmlFeed','Feed-Date-2015-07-07')
```

But How can we track this on google analytic from code behind?
Is there any alternative to achieve this?

Comment: Down voter what you not getting in this que?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to post events to Google Analytics via server-side API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503329/is-there-any-way-to-post-events-to-google-analytics-via-server-side-api)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this.

Google analytics event tracking from server side is possible.
so I need to call it, once get request for feed and then serve feed in response.

[Is there any way to post events to Google Analytics via server-side API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503329/is-there-any-way-to-post-events-to-google-analytics-via-server-side-api)

thank you.